# Як правильно перекласти словосполучення "употреблять внутрь" з російської мови українською?

Tags: переклад, росіянізм

Допоможіть перекласти словосполучення "употреблять внутрь" з російської мови українською. Ідеть про вживання напоїв, ліків тощо. Може, існує більш влучний відповідник, ніж "вживати всередину"?

Answer (score 2):

Часткова відповідь…

У випадку лікарських засобів *всередину* можна замінити на точніше зазначання того, як саме вживати: *[перорально](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%B2)* (тобто через рот), *ректально*, *інтравагінально*, *внутрішньом'язово*, *внутрішньовенно* тощо.

Дієслово *вживати* при цьому можна замінити на *вводити* або *приймати* (хоча дехто заперечує природність для української мови — чи то конкретно слова *прийом*, чи то всього гнізда *-й(о)м-* — але це наразі не є загальноприйнятою позицією).

Answer (score 2):

Знайшов с [Словнику Савченко](http://univer.nuczu.edu.ua/tmp_metod/1047/%D1%E0%E2%F7%E5%ED%EA%EE%20%CB.%20%C3._%D0%EE%F1%B3%E9%F1%FC%EA%EE-%F3%EA%F0%E0%BF%ED%F1%FC%EA%E8%E9%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%ED%E8%EA%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%EE%F1%EF%EE%EB%F3%F7%E5%ED%FC.%20%D2%F0%F3%E4%ED%EE%F9%B3%20%EF%E5%F0%E5%EA%EB%E0%E4%F3.pdf) переклад російського "принимать лекарство" (325 ст. ПДФ) - "**приймати ліки**". Дивимося значення слова в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryjmaty):

> **Вживати всередину**, ковтати (ліки). Я вигадав, що заслаб.. Підняв тривогу, мусив приймати краплі од живота і зіпсував великодній
>   сніданок (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955, 364);

Звідси ще один варіант - "**ковтати ліки**".

[Російсько-український словник](https://translate.academic.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C/ru/uk/) також ще пропонує:

**Заживати/зажити ліки**

**Пити/випити ліки** - а коли говоримо про напій, то також кажемо "випити ...", так само ще й можна сказати "зажити ...".